# What is a small piece that we pinch so that we can zip and unzip things?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

[image]

**What is a small piece that we pinch so that we can zip and unzip things?**

Do we call it "**a knob**" or something?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper) calls the moving part the _slider_ and the piece you take hold of the _pull tab_.

Comment: Or a *zipper pull*, or sometimes just a *pull*.

Comment: By the way, in cases like this you can usually just google "parts of a zipper" and get the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part that is pulled using finger and thumb is often called the pull, pull tab, or puller.

[image]

Comment: Or, as my wife says, 'the pully thing'.